# Create new file po in cakephp merge with old file po

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a po file by cake command. However, after editing some template file, I have to insert more string for translating. How could I created new po file by cake command with old translated string in old po file? Thanks and best regard.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are using source control, in which case it is easy... Svn or git will handle this for you.

If you are not, you're in for a long night of manual merging and hair pulling.

Comment: I don't know how to resolve by SVN . Because when I generate new PO file, all translated string will be deleted. How can I resolve conflict with them?

Comment: Now, I'm using SVN plug in in eclipse, I still have to manually copy translated string from server version back to client version, then make change to client version and commit it to server version. I don't see any much convenience here.